# React JS - Nesting components passed as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've written a container component in ReactJS and am passing in a prop to that component which is to be rendered as the 'main' content, like so:

```
class RegistrationContainer extends Component {

    render() {
        const MainContent = this.props.mainContent;

        return (
            <Row>
                <Col offset="lg-3" lg={6}>
                    <MainContent />
                </Col>
            </Row>
        );
    }

}

export default RegistrationContainer;
```

And I'm passsing to it a `mainContent` prop like so:

```
import RegistrationContainer from './RegistrationContainer';
import RegistrationEntryView from './RegistrationEntryView';

class RegistrationCodeEntry extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <RegistrationContainer mainContent={RegistrationEntryView} />
        );
    }
}

export default RegistrationCodeEntry;
```

My issue is that I would like `RegistrationEntryView` to have props, but can't seem to figure out how to define/pass in props on it.  If I do the following I get an error:

```
class RegistrationCodeEntry extends Component {

    render() {
        const RegistrationView = <RegistrationEntryView someProp="blah" /> ;
        return (
            <RegistrationContainer mainContent={RegistrationView} />
        );
    }
}

export default RegistrationCodeEntry;
```

Error is as follows:

> invariant.js?7313:42 Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected
>   a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: object. Check the render method of
>   `RegistrationContainer`.

Is this something that `this.props.children` could solve?  I've been struggling to get my head around the concept of that, so any advice on where I'm going wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: I think `this.props.children` would solve your problem. Return somethng like this in the `render()` method of `RegistrationCodeEntry`: `return (
      <RegistrationContainer><RegistrationEntryView someProp="blah" /></RegistrationContainer>
    );`

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i was after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this with `this.props.children` like this

```
class RegistrationCodeEntry extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <RegistrationContainer>
          // Render it as children
          <RegistrationEntryView someProp="blah" />
      </RegistrationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

then in your container

```
class RegistrationContainer extends Component {

  render() {

  const MainContent = this.props.mainContent;

  return (
    <Row>
      <Col offset="lg-3" lg={6}>
         // Render the passed children
        {this.props.children}
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i was after.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is correct. You just went wrong here:

```
<Row>
  <Col offset="lg-3" lg={6}>
    <MainContent />
  </Col>
</Row>
```

Instead do this:

```
<Row>
  <Col offset="lg-3" lg={6}>
    { MainContent }
  </Col>
</Row>
```

I personally think, this approach is better than using children.

When you did this - `const RegistrationView = <RegistrationEntryView someProp="blah" /> ;` The component was already rendered and converted to appropriate format. Hence you cannot re-render it with `<MainContent />`.
So using {} is correct in this case.

Good Luck!